# How to rewrite the following code since the FirebaseInstanceId() is deprecated?

Tags: firebase, android-studio

The code was found from a Youtube tutorial called realtime location firebase and it's important for my Final Year Project. I appreciate all the help that i could get. Thanks in advance.

```
private void updateToken(FirebaseUser firebaseUser) {
        DatabaseReference tokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.TOKENS);

        //Get Token
       FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                tokens.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(instanceIdResult.getToken());
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void updateToken(FirebaseUser firebaseUser) {
    DatabaseReference tokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(Common.TOKENS);

    FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getId()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                    tokens.child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .setValue(task.getResult());
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

also try some dependencies in build.gradle(:app)

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'